# Java - Draw components or images to screen without a window

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I am kind of new to programming but I already do know a lot. I have always stayed in the default window but now I'm at the point where I can't do things that I want to do with what I know. I'm trying to make a class that shows a custom window that is transparent, it is using a `JFrame` called `CFrame` but to set it transparent I have to use:

```
try
{
    AWTUtilities.setWindowOpaque(CFrame, false);
}

catch(Exception ex)
{
    System.err.println("Failed to set CFrame Opaque");
}
```

But since there are different JVM's AWTUtilities, which are from Sun, doesn't work. So it would be helpful if some one knows how to fix my problem or knows how to draw components and images to screen.

Comment: What's the problem exactly? You're trying to get it to make the window non-opaque, but what is happening when you do that?

Comment: I run Linux and Windows. Linux has JDK 7 and Windows has JDK 6. If I run my application on Linux I sometimes get problems with the non opaque and I forgot what it was on a Mac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can use Java 7, the window opacity stuff has been moved into the public API. See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html#uniform. Basically, there's now a `setOpacity` method in the `Frame` class, but the tutorial shows how to detect whether the graphics system even supports transparency, to "platform-proof" yourself.

As to general drawing with swing, there are stacks of tutorials on the web. Maybe start with this one: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/step1.html. Even the related questions that pop up here are going to have a wealth of info.

The book [Filthy Rich Clients](http://filthyrichclients.org/) is really good for advanced swing UIs.